# How to parse xsd String to fetch its elements using java?

Tags: java, xml, string, parsing, xsd

I need a solution on "How to parse a xml file and its xsd element's values"?

As a result of one of my web service method call, I will get an Java object which contains an xsd as Java String. This xsd contains many xsd:elements. I need to fetch one of the element called "AccountName" which contains a list of AccountNames in it. I need to use Java code here to fetch all this and store into one List. Here it is:

```
metadataXsd ----------->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org    /2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsd:element name="metadata">
    <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element id="md_37EE5DE8-996B-0371-A119-61B77FE6ABCF" name="Category" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation/>
        <xsd:appinfo>
          <label>Category</label>
          <key>Category</key>
          <searchable>true</searchable>
          <timeControl>false</timeControl>
          <description>Specify categories where the media content should be published</description>
        </xsd:appinfo>
      </xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="listType">
          <xsd:enumeration value="Industries &amp; Solutions"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Industries &amp; Solutions - Solutions Topics"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Industries &amp; Solutions - Industry Solutions"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Industries &amp; Solutions - Business Partners and Alliances"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Services"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Services - Business Services"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Services - IT Services"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Services - Outsourcing Services"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Services - Training"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Services - Additional Services"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Products"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Products - Software"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Products - Systems"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Products - Storage"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Products - Additional Products"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Support &amp; downloads"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Support &amp; downloads - Knowledge Center"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Support &amp; downloads - Knowledge Center - Education Assistant"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Support &amp; downloads - Technical Support"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Support &amp; downloads - Developer Support"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Support &amp; downloads - Supplier Support"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Support &amp; downloads - Former Products"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Support &amp; downloads - Downloads"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="My"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Interests"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element id="md_ACECFC0E-1F3B-8233-17B3-AEB96AF9D030" name="AccountName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation></xsd:documentation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
          <label>Account Name</label>
          <key>Account Name</key>
          <searchable>true</searchable>
          <timeControl>false</timeControl>
          <description>Specify the account that owns the media content</description>
        </xsd:appinfo>
      </xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="listType">
          <xsd:enumeration value="Analytics Business Unit Client Success Sales Eminence"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Digital"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Enterprise Media Team Enablement"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Enterprise Content and eSupport Services"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Global Delivery Center"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Digital Video Services New York"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Enterprise Social Solutions"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="GBS Knowledge"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="GPS Technology"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Global Private Digital Commercde"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Center"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="mix"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Essentials"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="References"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Learning Services"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="works"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Programs &amp; Operations"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="IBM Digital – CHQ Marketing"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Assistant"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Content Catalog"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Center"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="books"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="ser"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Marketing and Communications"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Middleware Client Success"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="PW"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Enablement"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Sales"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Systems Unit"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="Technical"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
```

From the above I need to fetch only AccountName element and store all of its values as one list and further process.

I tried the below code which converts the String to xml.

```
metadataXsd = metadataProfile.xsd;
                    if(metadataXsd != null) {
                        System.out.println("metadataXsd ----------->"+metadataXsd);
                            finalXmlDoc = stringToDom(metadataXsd);
                            System.out.println("finalXmlDoc ----------->"+finalXmlDoc);
                        }
                    }

public static Document stringToDom(String xmlSource) throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, TransformerException{
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
        DocumentBuilder builder;  
        try 
        {  
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
            Document doc = builder.parse( new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource))); 
            TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
            Source src = new DOMSource( doc );
            Result dest = new StreamResult( new File( "C:/AccountNames.xml" ) );
            System.out.println("Destination xml -------->"+dest);
            aTransformer.transform( src, dest );
            Document doc1 = builder.parse (new File("C:/AccountNames.xml")); 
            NodeList list = doc1.getElementsByTagName("xsd:element"); 

            for(int i = 0 ; i < list.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Element first = (Element)list.item(i);


            }
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } 
        return null;
    }
```

Now I need to get all the   values as a Java list. Please help me resolving this.

Comment: Hello Rajya, your question needs some improvement. You should first research for your self and try to solve it on your own. Then show us the relevant code with the specific problem. XSD is ordinary XML, so you can parse a XSD file like any other XML.

Comment: @vanje - I have tried some solution converting the string into xml and then reading the xsd. I am able to get all the elements but not sure how to get specific < <xsd:restriction base="listType"> for AccountName element. Thanks

Comment: First: `xsd` is a namespace prefix. So you should parse the XML with namespace awareness. Then, if you have all `element` elements. What is the next step? Find the one you are interested in, right? And if you have the right element node, go down to the restriction node. You should show a little bit more initiative. If you're stuck, google for it. Read a tutorial. Try something out. If this doesn't work, try something different. Don't wait that somebody hand you the solution on a silver platter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am not simply asking you for the solution. I am trying parallel and asking you for any ideas as I did not work on it earlier. Hope this is not the correct forum where I will post my technical questions. I will try other. I think no one expects the complete solution from someone without trying.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for my problem. Hope this helps somebody.

```
public static Document stringToDom(String xmlSource) throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, TransformerException{
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
        DocumentBuilder builder;  
        NodeList nodeList = null;
        List<String> accountNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try 
        {  
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource))); 
            TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
            Source src = new DOMSource(doc);
            Result dest = new StreamResult(new File("C:/AccountNames.xml" ) );
            aTransformer.transform( src, dest );
            Document doc1 = builder.parse (new File("C:/AccountNames.xml")); 
            NodeList list = doc1.getElementsByTagName("xsd:element");
            for(int i = 0 ; i < list.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Element first = (Element)list.item(i);
                if(first.hasAttributes()) {
                    String attrname = first.getAttribute("name");
                    if(attrname.equalsIgnoreCase("AccountName")) {
                        NodeList list1 = first.getElementsByTagName("xsd:enumeration");
                        for(int j=0;j<list1.getLength();j++) {
                            Element sec = (Element)list1.item(j);
                            if(sec.hasAttributes()) {
                                String attr = sec.getAttribute("value");
                                System.out.println(attr);
                                accountNamesList.add(attr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
             }
            System.out.println("accountNamesList.size()"+accountNamesList.size());

            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } 
        return null;
    }
```

Thanks,
Rajya

Answer (score 0):

Use an XPath expression (you'll need an XPathFactory) with the desired predicates

`*//xsd:element[@name="AccountName"]//xsd:restriction[@base="listType"]`